# Converting a 24 hr time string to datetime and keeping the 24 hr time

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm at a loss here, and I realise I may be going the long way around, but I can't figure it out.
I have a datetime in UTC, curr.
It is not being saved in 24 hr time, so I can convert it to a string s, which is indeed a string in 24 hr time. Now I want to save it back as a datetime still retaining the 24 hr time, but when I write foo out it is still being displayed in 24 hr time. How do I get the current Utc time in not just a DateTime, but a 24 hr DateTime?

```
var curr = DateTime.UtcNow;
String s = curr.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
DateTime foo = DateTime.Parse(s);
Console.WriteLine(foo);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DateTime` object does not store time in the form of hours/minutes/seconds as we traditionally think of time, instead under the hood it is storing the number of "ticks" (100 nanosecond intervals) since a beginning point (I believe 1st January 1AD).

When you call `.ToString()` on a `DateTime` object, it will default to the standard date format encoded, which is the AM/PM format.

If you want it to display as 24hr time then you have to give it a format as you did here:

`String s = curr.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");`

Answer (score 2):

A `DateTime` just has a value not a format, so this is wrong: "It is not being saved in 24 hr time", because "24hr time" is about a formatted-datetime-string.

`Console.WriteLine(foo)` calls `DateTime.ToString` without parameters. Depending on your current culture you will then get a formatted datetime-string. If you want to ensure a specific format, use [`DateTime.ToString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings) with a culture and/or a format string(like you did).

So a `DateTime` is just a value(ticks since January 1, 0001). If you want to display it use `DateTime.ToString`, until then keep it as a `DateTime`.

Read: [Standard date and time format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings) and [Custom date and time format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)